# copying sqlite3 db while being read

Tags: sqlite

I have a script that was reading data from a sqlite3 database and while this script was running I made a copy of the database `cp mydatabase mydatabase.bak`. Will this affect either the script that was reading from the db or the copy of the db? I had a look at the sqlite documentation here [0] but I didn't put a lock on the db as per the instructions.

[0] http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the file should be analogous to another application reading the database, so it shouldn't be a problem. Multiple applications can safely read the database file at the same time (per the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)).

As another point, consider that you can read from a database even if the database and its directory both lack write permissions. Since in that scenario there's no way for the reading application to be modifying the database file or creating a temp file that needs to be incorporated into it, there's no way for any of a number of simultaneously reading applications to affect what any of the others see.